# View is not returning attributes stored in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I am attempting to return which user posted a comment, along with the time they posted the comment.

I have a model for comments

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class comments extends Model
    {
        protected $guarded = [];

        public function adjustments()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'adjustments')
            ->withTimestamps();
        }
    }
```

A pivot table which tracks which users posted which comments

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('adjustments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->unsignedInteger('comments_id')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

An empty adjustments model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class adjustment extends Model
{
    //
}
```

In `php artisan tinker` when `$comment = App\comment::first();` and `$user = App\user::first();` I'm able to successfully attach a user_id to a comment_id using `$comment->adjustments()->attach($user->id)` and calling `App\adjustments::all();` will correctly return

> ```
> => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2935
>      all: [
>        App\adjustment {#2941
>          id: 1,
>          user_id: 1,
>          comments_id: 1,
>          created_at: "2019-11-16 17:05:10",
>          updated_at: "2019-11-16 17:05:10",
>        },
>      ],
>    }
> ```

When I'm trying to show the adjustments in my view, I get an empty list.

```
  @foreach ($comment->adjustments as $user)
        <li>{{$user->name}} on {{$user->pivot->updated_at}}</li>
    @endforeach
```

In my products controller (a user makes comments on products) I have the following code in my show function

```
public function show(products $product, comments $comment, User $user)
{
    return view ('products.show', compact('product'), compact('comment'));
}
```

Comment: You could try to update the `comments` model relation to `$this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'adjustments', 'user_id', 'comments_id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't need a pivot table. Becasue here you has one to many relation. User can create many comment. & one comment is belongs one user.In user model add this

```
public function comments()
{
return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

& comments table u have a foreign key user_id.

in comment model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id')
}
```

```
public function show(products $product, comments $comment, User $user)
{
    $comments=Comment::with('user')->all();
    return view ('products.show', compact(['product','comments']));
}
```

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
        <li>{{$comment->user->name}} on {{$comment->updated_at}}</li>
    @endforeach
```

Then you can acces all comments table data with a user

Comment: Ah thank you! Any chance you would you be able to help me with the syntax for pulling out the comment author? Thanks again

Comment: Here's the migration!

            `$table->increments('id');`
            `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`
            `$table->unsignedInteger('products_id');`
            `$table->text('comment');`
            `$table->timestamps();`
            
          `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

           `$table->foreign('products_id')->references('id')->on('products');`

Comment: Hello again, thanks for your help so far. 
Using the code above I get an error `BadMethodCallException`
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`

It highlights `$comments=comments::with('user')->all();`
(i've changed it from `Comment` to `comments` to reflect the name of my comments class)

Comment: Nevermind @albus_severus I managed to get it working by clearing my cache.

Thanks so much for all your help!